# FB share on Wordpress blog keeps showing wrong image on already shared pages

Tags: facebook, image, share

The FB share on my wordpress blog (wordoptimist.com) keeps showing the wrong image when I want to share the pages that I've already shared before modifying the meta og.

For the pages I've never shared before its displaying the new image with the description I've
wrote down in the meta og's.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Marjolein De Praetere

Answer (score 0):

Use the open graph meta tags. On the <head> section of you page's HTML, add the following line

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://source/to/your/image/file"/>
```

This will fix the problem.

Comment: that is already in my code. Like I said in the pages I've never shared before, Its showing that image. But when I just installed te fb share it took one of my images from the banner when I  to shared. Then I added the meta properties. And know its showing 2 different kind of Images: the wrong image for the pages I shared before adding meta properties and the new image and description when I share the pages that I didn't share before adding meta prop's. It's some kind of caching I think. But I tried on different pc's and there is no difference

Comment: Please check the page source HTML (in any browser, just hit view source) and check what is the value of og:image tag. Cause I think the value it renders in that tag is wrong on those pages where you are getting the wrong shared images. Just my $0.02

Comment: I've checked the source on every page and it is always the correct image. I will ask tonight to some friends to test it again on there pc's. Could there be caching on my IP, because all my collegue's have the same in the office. thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: Alright, you are right in this case. the images are coming from the cached source. Here is an article which will help you to understand how to clear the cache of your old urls http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/